# MediaPlayer Error 100,0 Titanium Appcelerator Android

Tags: android, media-player

Have my code set up so I press a button and a sound plays:

```
//button code    
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : '/images/ok-button-up.png',
                width : 185,
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                touchEnabled : 'true',
});

//sound code
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
    url: "sounds/sound.wav",
    preload: true
});

//event
image.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    sound.play();
});
```

I get this error in console:

```
[WARN] :   AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
[WARN] :   IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Analytics Service Started
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Stopping Analytics Service
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
```

I am using Titanium SDK version 5.3.1.GA

I am using Genymotion emulator, running a Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19

Any help is appreciated